# Why is my cat's nose turning black?

Tags: cats

I noticed discoloration on my cat's nose and mouth area, I researched it, some indicate it's dirt or bruising but it's not getting any better (I am trying to get him to a vet but due to covid it's gotten very hard to move around) but it's really starting to look concerning [image: what can I till I can take him to the vet]